# Architecture for an Enterprise Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, workflow-foundation-4

I am going to create an enterprise web application ( Its a personal dream project), and I admit that I might not know all the technologies and stacks required to build it. Build I am postive I can learn them quickly. I am intersted to know which architecture would suit my software here. I was thinking about Workflow Foundation, but was not sure if its the right approach. Any other tools or architectural patterns that will help me.

**More about my application**

The expected end users of the application will be the general public and various Government departments. Each of these government departments will have several sub departments who also requires access.

**The Complexity**

﻿1. The staffs in these government department might be transfered or promoted or depromoted at any time.

1. A particular role or function might be moved from one particular department to another at point of time.
2. Number of departments might increase or decrease at point of time.
3. Should have easy access managment at department level and individual level.

**Extra Complexity (If its possible)**

﻿﻿1. Data in the reports can can be easily changed( example adding another column , or even manupliting datas)  , without changing the basic application logic or structure.

Comment: When you say architecture, you mean framework?

Comment: I did not mean Framework. I intend to use ASP.net framework(preferably MVC) , as I am more comfortable with it. Its more about how i could design the architecture of the software so that its flexible enough. I found that using a workflow management system like Windows Workflow Foundation will help me. However I am not 100% convinced. AS i find mixed opinion, and some of them are really outdated reviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did several government projects, to talk about a few of my experience:

Governments usually hierarchical management, divided into: state, county, city, etc., divided into sections for each level of government units responsible for different tasks, can be called "role", the staff belonging to a administrative division, with one or more roles.

General government departments, higher-level units can manage subordinate data, so, using incremental encoder is relatively simple, such as 330102, 33 (state), 01 (county), 02 (City), with: xxx like '3301% 'access to 3301 County (including sub-districts) of the data; Each role has a number of menu items, a very simple permissions system, no elaboration.

In addition, about custom fields, you need to add a metadata dictionary, which store each report fields, each field has a specified property belongs to which administrative divisions, when the user logs in, according to the user's administrative divisions retrieve the corresponding Fields list. Due to the different sections of the view different reports, so it does not need additional fields.

These are my conditions encountered, may not meet your case, for reference only.

#### Additions:

I used Asp.net 2.0 technology, database using Oracle (customer requirements).Use the WebForm to generate the user interface, do not use any other frameworks. Because other frameworks with learning costs, and demand change mostly need Coding. I want to achieve when there are changes in demand, the customer can adjust, do not rely on any other tools and environments.

Asp.net, I use the most is its WebUserControl (ascx). I put the user interface definitions stored in the database, when the user opens the document (report),generated user controls, and then combined into the WebForm.

```
//public class Common_CustomBill:Page
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    //User Interface Definition retrieved from the database
    LoadBillItems();
    foreach(DataRow ARow in BillItems.Rows)
    {
        HtmlTableCell ACell = new HtmlTableCell();
        HtmlTableRow ATableRow  = new HtmlTableRow();
        ATableRow.Cells.Add(ACell);
        //Depending on the type load control
        NovaNet.WebBase.BillItem AItem = LoadControl("BillItem/" + ARow["type"].ToString() + ".ascx") as NovaNet.WebBase.BillItem;
        AItem.OrderId = ARow["OrderId"].ToString();
        AItem.ID = string.Format("C{0:X}{1}", Session.SessionID.GetHashCode(), ARow["OrderId"]);
        if(P.OftenFunction.SafeToString(ARow["Border"]) == "none")
        {
            ACell.Controls.Add(AItem);
        }
        else
        {
            HtmlGenericControl FIELDSET = new HtmlGenericControl("FIELDSET");
            HtmlGenericControl Legend = new HtmlGenericControl("legend");
            FIELDSET.Controls.Add(Legend);
            Legend.InnerHtml = ARow["label"].ToString();
            FIELDSET.Controls.Add(AItem);
            ACell.Controls.Add(FIELDSET);
        }
        tabMain.Rows.Add(ATableRow);
        AItem.BillData = Data;
        //initialize the control
        AItem.InitiData(ARow["content"] as byte[],ModuleName);
    }
}
```

User control is initialized, the different types of user controls behave differently. For example, the multi-selection control is initialized CheckBoxList Items property. Special, custom type controls, initialization is generated and loaded into a separate ascx file.

```
public partial class Common_BillItem_CustomControl:NovaNet.WebBase.BillItem
{
    public override void OnInitiData()
    {
        base.OnInitiData();
        //FData is incoming "initialization data"
        string Value = FData["code"].ToString();
        //Disk file generated
        string AFileName = "~/Temp/" + ModuleName +"_"+ Value.GetHashCode().ToString("X") + ".ascx";
        if(!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(Server.MapPath(AFileName))))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(Server.MapPath(AFileName)));

        if(!File.Exists(Server.MapPath(AFileName)))
        {
            using (StreamWriter AWriter = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath(AFileName),false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                AWriter.Write(Value);
                AWriter.Close();
            }
        }
        //Loaded into the interface
        Controls.Add(LoadControl(AFileName));
    }

}
```

IIS dynamic compilation great. Load "ascx file" Generate "dll files", follow the direct loading "dll file".

Comment: Partially answers my question.  But how do you do the coding. The simple and manual way or do you use any tools or framework

Comment: Adding a bit UI processing logic that may not make it clear, would like to know what you tell me